# Google blogger is not producing cname records, it is just accepting the custom domain

Tags: dns, blogger

I have a domain,I used it with one blog then it just worked fine. but now I have removed the custom url and added it to my another blog and now blogger is not generating cname records it is just accepting the domain. And I deleted the cname records of old blog in bigrock. plz help me.my domain name is "www.diplomaticengineers.com". thank you.

Comment: I think this question would be better answered at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) as this about and DNS configuration. StackOverflow is for programming related issues.

Comment: How long ago did these changes take place?